# What is this stuff in the wall behind my bathroom? (Is it asbestos?)

Tags: plumbing, insulation, asbestos

I'm planning to have some bathtub faucet stems replaced, and I'd like to do some due diligence before hand. The plumber will have to do some work in the area pictured. The picture shows the access point from the bedroom wall behind the bathroom, where the pipes are. There is some sort of hard insulation, foam, or paste (or something?) shown that the pipes pass through. My question is, should I be concerned about the work being done here? Is this material asbestos, and/or how *likely* is it to be asbestos? Or what is it?

Thank you for your thoughts!!!

[image]

Comment: I have no idea if this (which looks similar to some stuff in my house...) is asbestos or not. But it is extremely important to keep in mind that asbestos is only a problem when the fibers can get out. Covered? No problem. Solid? No problem. So even if this is asbestos, working around it is perfectly safe - the only real issue is if the plumber has to cut it, potentially releasing fibers/dust/etc.

Comment: Adding age of house to the question might help a bit.  Less chance of asbestos in newer houses.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the only way to know for sure if this is asbestos is to have it tested at a lab. We can't tell by looking at a picture.

Comment: If all the plumber is doing is replacing faucet stems, that is done from the front on the other side of the wall - so no issue. If you have to mess with the back side be sure to mask up. Looks like tile grout on wire backing to me.

Comment: Unless you're planning on cutting into the stuff it really doesn't matter if it contains asbestos or not. Any asbestos which might be there is very well encapsulated by the plaster it's mixed in with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the backside of a plaster wall that was applied to metal mesh as the backing material. Basically, they put up something like chicken wire and apply plaster to that to form the wall.

The other material around the pipes is likely some sort of putty, like duct seal or plumber's putty (looks like plumber's putty to me).

It's impossible to know if any of this contains asbestos. You would have to take some samples and send them to a testing lab to know for sure.

As has been mentioned already, asbestos is  mostly found in older homes/materials. So if your house was built in the 90s for example, the chance of any of this containing asbestos is very small. Also, as long as the material is not disturbed and is not fraying/crumbling otherwise, it is fine to just leave it alone.

Since you're saying some plumbing fixtures will be replaced, I guess your options are to send sample to get tested, or just take the risk. As far as I know, asbestos exposure is more of an occupational hazard, if you have a sort of one time minor exposure from removing this tiny amount of material, there is probably very little risk on that. But I guess the right thing to do if you are concerned is to get the material tested.

Comment: If you played "snowballs" with asbestos then you are at risk (I have acquaintances that did so and are ill...) One time minimal exposure is a different game. Worry more about breathing all those carcinogens when walking down the road - all those cars burning benzene...

Comment: 100% that it's plaster through metal lathe. However, that type of construction _might_ put it prior to the US ban on asbestos. However, I'm not sure if asbestos was ever used as an additive to plaster. That might be a point for the OP to research himself. Also, 100% agree that so long as it's not disturbed it's perfectly fine, and that a 1-time exposure is _highly unlikely_ (though not-zero) to cause any issues.

Comment: some of the metal mesh is visible to in the bottom left.